# Transaction receipt status failing

Tags: testrpc, ropsten, web3.py

I have written and deployed my smart contract in Ropsten and all the calls are failing with status failed . Says out of gas but same problem if I passed additional gas argument. 
I am using web3 python transact method .

Transactions : https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x56eafd2f8528875d779bb1b7290a8608d8fcc72e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the source code is hard to tell anything.

From the parity trace of this transaction [0xe5f8ab47..](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0xe5f8ab4784525148c2d299a6d041f08228cb3f400452d6757f0126e18e170fda&type=parity), it appears you contract is trying to deploy a new contract and it runs out of gas.

```
{
    "action": {
      "from": "0xdf27f7816f2fa03b71e53b6393f4d22e00c9ec41",
      "gas": "0xe1bfa",
      "init": "0x606060405234156200......",
      "value": "0x0"
    },
    "blockHash": "0xa40eb727674cd11763a00c64a6c42cf3a1ea43ca370cce3b57f22c9d764bfa09",
    "blockNumber": 2163032,
    "error": "Out of gas",
    "subtraces": 0,
    "traceAddress": [
      0
    ],
    "transactionHash": "0xe5f8ab4784525148c2d299a6d041f08228cb3f400452d6757f0126e18e170fda",
    "transactionPosition": 1,
    "type": "create"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @ismael. When I increase the gas limit it is success. I need to replace the new contract object instantiation with struct data type to reduce gas cost.